# SQL Concat text from 2 different tables (Multipart messages)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a query in PHP that will give me rows joined together by ID from 2 different tables.

My first table is "**outbox**" that looks like this.

```
TextDecoded  |  ID   |  CreatorID
Helllo, m..  |  123  |    Martin
Yes, I wi..  |  124  |    Martin
```

My second table is "**outbox_multipart**" that looks very similar.

```
TextDecoded  |  ID   |  SequencePosition
my name i..  |  123  |         2
s Martin.    |  123  |         3
ll do tha..  |  124  |         2
t tomorrow.  |  124  |         3
```

In this example there are 2 messages that both consists of **3 parts**. The first part is always in outbox table and the rest of them are in outbox_multipart table ordered by **SequencePosition**.

So the expected result of a query would be this.

```
       TextDecoded            |  ID   |   CreatorID
Helllo, my name is Martin.    |  123  |    Martin
Yes, I wil do that tomorrow.  |  124  |    Martin
```

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Yes it's possible, either with php or with mysql cursors see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Inner Join` between the two tables using `ID`.
- [`Group_Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function allows us to concatenate expressions/column values in a Group, with a flexibility of custom sorting, and our choice of delimiter. We can concat `outbox_multipart.TextDecoded`, based on ascending `Order By` of `outbox_multipart.SequencePosition`; and use empty string `''` as delimiter.
- Use [`Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to concatenate the fixed starting substring `outbox.TextDecoded`, to the result string of `Group_concat`.

Try:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(ob.TextDecoded, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(obm.TextDecoded 
                      ORDER BY obm.SequencePosition ASC 
                      SEPARATOR ''
                     )
        ) AS TextDecoded, 
  ob.ID, 
  ob.creatorID
FROM outbox AS ob 
JOIN outbox_multipart AS obm ON obm.ID = ob.ID 
GROUP BY 
  ob.ID, 
  ob.creatorID
```

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect! Except I had to remove the | before GROUP BY because it was giving me a syntax error.

Comment: @MartinZeltin ohh that's a typo. Will edit that. Happy to help :)